# Running bashscript/Unix line in Vim

Tags: bash

I wonder is there anyway to run a bash script by line (or at least last line) in the current editor or any other ways to run the last line of a file? For example Vim as I am using it. The reason for this is because I want to save the code in a file for later reference, if I just do it directly in Terminal, I need to copy it by hand and run it by hand line by line.

Thank you very much.

Comment: *"If I just do it directly  in Terminal, I need to copy it by hand"* -- huh?

Comment: *"I want to save the code in a file for later reference"* -- huh x2?

Comment: Sounds *exactly* like you are looking for Emacs with `M-x shell` *smirk*

Answer (score 1):

`:execute '!' . getline("$")` should do it for the last line. In order for a numbered line (for example line 42), use `getline(42)`.

You might want to use a mapping in order to reduce typing:

```
:nnoremap ,exec :execute '!' . getline(".")<CR>
```

With this mapping in place, the line the cursor is on is execute in a shell by typing `,exec`.